# SQL Server concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am trying to concat columns with a comma `,` as the delimiter.

My concern is that any column with `NULL` will end up with only a `,` and if two columns are NULL, I'd get `,,`.

How to dynamically find and replace these multiple commatas `,,,` to a single `,`? Please support

Comment: Please share your query.

Comment: Try using `ISNULL` after the concatenation.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2017+ just use `concat_ws` which ignores nulls

Eg

```
select concat_ws(', ','abc',null,'def')
```

> Result: abc, def

Answer (score 1):

Use `CONCAT_WS` to concatenate several columns and skip nulls:

```
select concat_ws(' ', 'hallo', null, 'world', null);
```

returns 'hello world'.

In your case you want a comma as a separator, hence:

```
select concat_ws(',', col1, col2, col3, col4) from mytable;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b55f64bd22f5e20e23f156ad23ab85e0

Answer (score 0):

One quick trick is using [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to null check.
If not null concat comma+string, else an empty string.

The ideal solution is [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which does like string.Join in C#

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
select concat('hallo' + ', ', null + ', ', 'world' + ', ', null + ', ');
```